# window.location with relative url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use window.location to redirect to a relative url

this variable

```
var redirect = $(this).attr('title');
```

has this value

```
../../000_Movies/_assets/playlist.html
```

this wont redirect

```
window.location = redirect;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to redirect to relative pages you should use:

```
 window.location.href = "../../000_Movies/_assets/playlist.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.location.href = $(this).attr('title');
```